# R studio code execution error (file name conversion error)

Tags: r, rstudio, execution

[image]

Suddenly above error messages come when I type a single character on my R studio script window. What is the reason? And Is there somebody tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Abruptly those warning messages are silent. I think this happened because of my deleting Rhistory file, RData file in Working Directory and deleting some setting files in rstudio-desktop folder.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this problem is associated with using non-English characters in the directory name (for packages, working directories etc.). In your case it is connected to auto-completion `basename(.rs.listIndexedPackages())` - hence when you are typing a character an error is thrown. See the similar problem [Issue loading data of “file name conversion problem - name too long?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208134/issue-loading-data-in-r-of-file-name-conversion-problem-name-too-long).

Generally it advisable not to use non-English characters for directory name. And if the above mentioned error was thrown, you would either clear the RStudio environment by deleting temporary RStudio files or rename related directories from Korean to English.