# Issue loading data of "file name conversion problem - name too long?"

Tags: r, import, rstudio

I tried to open Excel data using import data in the RStudio, but I got this error:

> file name conversion problem - name too long?

See the session screenshot below:

[image: R Error]

What is the problem, and how can I handle this?

Comment: welcome to SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question title to something like that: R Studio: "File name conversion error - name too long?" error importing data

Comment: I think the photo clearly shows the issue. Fabulous, have you tried using the actual code instead of trying to use RStudio to load the file? It looks like you have a problem because the path name has non-English characters in it. Try typing into the console `dataset <- read_csv("c:/ <copy rest of path> /Affect.txt")`

Answer (score 3):

Answer goes out to Adam Sampson.

It looks like you have a problem because the path name has non-English characters in it. You have two option:

- rename directory into English then use "Import Text Data";
- read a dataset from a console using command `dataset <- read_csv("c:/ <copy rest of path> /Affect.txt")`.