# Upload an EPUB file in R

Tags: r, file, epub

I'm trying to read an EPUB file in r. It is placed in the working directory. I wrote this code:

```
library(epubr)
library(tm)
x <- epub("Perchisuonalacampana.epub") # parse entire e-book
```

But I obtained the following error:

```
Error in file.exists(path) : 
 file name conversion problem -- name too long?
```

(My EPUB file contains a novel.)

**EDIT**

```
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Standard/Downloads/aaa"
list.files()
[1] "dtm from pdf.R"            "Perchisuonalacampana.epub"
```

Comment: Are you sure that that file comes with the package? This works: `file <- system.file("dracula.epub", package = "epubr")`.

Comment: Yes, but I have stored a file, Perchisuonalacampana.epub, on my directory.  I thought it also worked for different files

Comment: If it's *your* file then it's not a *system* file, meaning, a data file packaged with `epubr`. Try just `epub("path/to/Perchisuonalacampana.epub")`.

Comment: Thank you, but I obtained: Error in file.exists(path) :   file name conversion problem -- name too long?

Comment: Change to the directory where the file is and try just the filename, there will be n need for a full pathname.

Comment: is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208134/issue-loading-data-of-file-name-conversion-problem-name-too-long

Comment: Can you share the output of `getwd()` and `list.files()`?

Comment: @Paul Thanks. I edited my post.

Comment: Can you change the file + folder names to something simple? I wonder if the file name has some weird characters

Comment: Check version EPUB

Comment: Try change version file https://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-epub

Answer (score 0):

From these two sources (they are nearly the same):

1. [rdocumentation.org](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/epubr/versions/0.6.1)
2. [docs.ropensci.org](https://docs.ropensci.org/epubr/)

It seems as though you need to do add the `system.file()`:

```r
library(epubr)
library(tm)

file <- system.file("Perchisuonalacampana.epub", package = "epubr")
x <- epub(file) # parse entire e-book
```

Not sure if these help any more but here are two more sources for a slightly different approach:

1. [docs.ropensci.org](https://docs.ropensci.org/epubr/reference/epub.html)
2. [rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/cran/epubr/man/epub.html)