# How to solve the "file name conversion problem -- name too long?" error when rendering a publication in Bookdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, gitbook

I'm having problems to render a publication in Bookdown. The error message sugests a kind of size problem in some file, but I have no idea how to identify it.

Found these related answers: [answer1](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/451), [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208134/issue-loading-data-of-file-name-conversion-problem-name-too-long), [answer3](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/486), but none of them solved my problem.

Thanks for any help.

> Error in file.exists(f) : file name conversion problem -- name too long? Calls: local ... local_resources -> grep -> is.factor -> unique -> file.exists Interrupted execution  Error: bookdown::render_book() failed to render the output format 'bookdown::gitbook'. Interrupted execution Exited with status 1.

This is my _bookdown.yml file configuration:

```
delete_merged_file: true
new_session: yes
language:
  label:
    fig: 'Figura '
    tab: 'Tabela '
  ui:
    chapter_name: "Capítulo"
```

And this is my _output.yml file:

```
  lib_dir: assets
  css: style.css
  includes:
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">Relatório Geral de Gastos Públicos em 2021"</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
    download: null
    sharing:
      facebook: no
      linkedin: yes
      whatsapp: yes
    info: no
bookdown::pdf_book:
  #pandoc_args: --top-level-division=chapter
  keep_text: yes
  keep_tex:  true
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  template: template.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  extra_dependencies: ["flafter"]
  toc_unnumbered: no
  fig_caption: yes
  toc_depth: 3
bookdown::epub_book: default
```

Comment: Is the book being split into multiple files for the web? Perhaps a chapter name is very long and causing this?

Comment: @jtbayly I used a basic template of Bookdown... the way I understand the bookdown functioning, when the book version  in html  is rendered it renders an index.html file and also other html files for each one of the book chapters... I shortened the title length of some of my chapters (the long ones), but the same error message continues to pop up. Thanks anyway,

Comment: Are there non-english characters in any of the chapter or section titles? If I were you, I'd try deleting all but the first chapter, and see if the problem persists. Try to narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: @jtbayly - I have 9 chapters and one appendix... I deleted the chapters, from the last ones to the fist and find out the problems start at some point in chapter 7 ... up to chapter 6  the rendering process is ok.. but I still couldn' t figure out what is causing the error... thanks!

Comment: That's great you got it narrowed down that far. I'm not sure if you've tried the following, but here's what I'd recommend: Try working with just chapter 7. Make sure it errors to confirm that's where the (or one of the) problem(s) is. Then try changing the title of the chapter to a simple English word. Then try the same with its sections. If it still won't build, try removing any images (if you have any), and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @jtbayly - After many hours of dedication I finally discovered that the rendering problem was being caused by one of the references in chapter 7, in particular, by the reference access link (see bellow). I couldn't find the real reason, but I suspect it might be due to some special characters (%), although I also have special characters in other references and chapters.... At the end I 'solved the problem' by deleting the link for this reference only... I hope this information can help others facing similar situations. Thanks!!  **http://www.avesmarinhas.com.br/Cap%EDtulo%2010.pdf**