# Error in dir.exists(x) : file name conversion problem -- name too long?

Tags: r, rstudio, reticulate

I am trying to import a .py file in RStudio and I am getting the error message:

> ```
> Error in dir.exists(x) : file name conversion problem -- name too long?)
> ```

I have already tried to run it through a path that only contains English letters and it didn't work. Also, the output of `list.files()` includes the file I'm trying to import.

```
library(reticulate)
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

setwd("C:/Users/Κατερίνα/Nextcloud/Multipic_Exp.1")

source_python("euler.py") --> Here I get the error message.


The traceback() output: 

12: dir.exists(x)
11: utils::file_test("-d", version_dir)
10: read_python_versions_from_registry("HCU", key = "PythonCore")
9: rbind(read_python_versions_from_registry("HCU", key = "PythonCore"), 
       read_python_versions_from_registry("HLM", key = "PythonCore"), 
       windows_registry_anaconda_versions())
8: py_versions_windows()
7: python_conda_versions()
6: py_discover_config(required_module, use_environment)
5: (function() {
       op <- options(reticulate.python.initializing = TRUE)
       on.exit(options(op), add = TRUE)
       py_discover_config(required_module, use_environment)
   })()
4: initialize_python(required_module, use_environment)
3: ensure_python_initialized()
2: py_run_file(file, local = FALSE, convert = convert)
1: source_python("euler.py")

My sessionInfo():
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253  LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253    LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.7     purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.4.0     tidyr_1.1.3     tibble_3.1.2   
 [8] ggplot2_3.3.5   tidyverse_1.3.1 reticulate_1.26

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.6.1     compiler_4.1.0   dbplyr_2.1.1     tools_4.1.0     
 [7] lubridate_1.8.0  jsonlite_1.8.4   lifecycle_1.0.3  gtable_0.3.0     lattice_0.20-44  pkgconfig_2.0.3 
[13] png_0.1-7        rlang_1.0.6      reprex_2.0.1     Matrix_1.3-3     cli_3.4.1        DBI_1.1.1       
[19] rstudioapi_0.13  haven_2.4.1      xml2_1.3.2       withr_2.4.2      httr_1.4.2       fs_1.5.2        
[25] hms_1.1.0        generics_0.1.0   vctrs_0.5.1      rprojroot_2.0.2  grid_4.1.0       tidyselect_1.1.1
[31] here_1.0.1       glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1         fansi_0.5.0      readxl_1.3.1     modelr_0.1.8    
[37] magrittr_2.0.3   scales_1.1.1     backports_1.2.1  ellipsis_0.3.2   rvest_1.0.2      assertthat_0.2.1
[43] colorspace_2.0-2 utf8_1.2.1       stringi_1.7.6    munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.7.8      crayon_1.4.1
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of the file `euler.py`, probably the problem is on the file being imported?

Comment: Here's the link to the file: https://github.com/jbakermans/stimulus-history-euler-tours/blob/main/euler.py

Comment: From what I understand there doesn't seem to be a problem in the file I want to import. I checked the option Inspect element after right clicking on the specific chuck and apparently RStudio failed to load the resource. I don't understand why though.

Comment: Sorry that I can't be of much help, just brainstorming, but maybe try changing the directory name: `Multipic_Exp.1`, to something like `Multipic_Exp_1`?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help, I'm afraid!

Comment: You mentioned already trying with only English characters on the path, but so far that is the only lead that I seem to find regarding this issue, for example on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208134/issue-loading-data-of-file-name-conversion-problem-name-too-long (which doesn't have an accepted answer by the way), and some others very similar, also without solutions. Can you try once more, on a completely different path, with just English characters, with not special characters like `.` on the name, etc, and see if you get exactly the same error?

Comment: I tried that again, I even re-downloaded the files directly in the "new" path and re-run the code, but it doesn't work. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Katerina have you found a solution? I have exactly the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but since I had the same problem just now, I will suggest a "hardware work-around".

Based on other discussions, the problem for most people will be with the file path containing letters that are not used in English.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Κατερίνα/Nextcloud/Multipic_Exp.1")
```

On a private computer, one could change these names (changing Κατερίνα into Katerina), but you may not want to do that. Also, if you're using a computer at work/ school, etc., you may not be able to change the name of the directory.

Placing the file on an external harddrive (i.e. a memory stick) may bypass troublesome directory names.